# VB.Net make draggable controls not go outside the form

Tags: vb.net

I have a custom control that is draggable using the code below, but the problem is that i can move the control outside the form.

```
    Private Sub ObjCan_MouseMove(sender As Object, e As MouseEventArgs) Handles Me.MouseMove

    If e.Button = Windows.Forms.MouseButtons.Left Then

        Me.Location = New Point(FormGame.PointToClient(MousePosition).X - 16, FormGame.PointToClient(MousePosition).Y - 16)

    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Only allow the location to change if it's within the forms bounds. You will have to subtract the objects width and height to get accurate bounds.

Comment: Wrote this but doesn't work

Comment: If New Rectangle(New Point(0, 0), New Point(Me.FindForm.Width, Me.FindForm.Height)).Contains(Me.Location.X + 48, Me.Location.Y + 48) Then

Answer (score 0):

Set [Cursor.Clip](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.windows.forms.cursor.clip(v=vs.90)) to limit mouse movement:

> Gets or sets the bounds that represent the clipping rectangle for the
>   cursor. A clipped cursor is allowed to move only within its clipping
>   rectangle.

Here's a quick example with a Label.  Note that if you moved the Label into a different container, like a Panel, the code would still work and the Label would be confined to the Panel bounds instead:

```
Public Class Form1

    Private PrevClip As Rectangle

    Private Sub Label1_MouseDown(sender As Object, e As MouseEventArgs) Handles Label1.MouseDown
        PrevClip = Cursor.Clip
        Dim ctl As Control = DirectCast(sender, Control)
        Dim ctlContainer As Control = ctl.Parent
        Cursor.Clip = ctlContainer.RectangleToScreen(New Rectangle(0, 0, ctlContainer.ClientSize.Width - ctl.Width, ctlContainer.ClientSize.Height - ctl.Height))
    End Sub

    Private Sub Label1_MouseMove(sender As Object, e As MouseEventArgs) Handles Label1.MouseMove
        If e.Button = MouseButtons.Left Then
            Dim ctl As Control = DirectCast(sender, Control)
            Dim ctlContainer As Control = ctl.Parent
            ctl.Location = ctlContainer.PointToClient(Cursor.Position)
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub Label1_MouseUp(sender As Object, e As MouseEventArgs) Handles Label1.MouseUp
        Cursor.Clip = PrevClip
    End Sub

End Class
```